# Outer product based Conv filters consume disproportionately high memory

Tags: memory-leaks, tensorflow

The minimum reproducible example is in this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/sahiliitm/bed9511d15ba0c45adf3c33210d59232). The issue is of a disproportionately large memory usage.

I modified the cifar10 example which ships with tensorflow to use outer-product of 3 vectors as the weights of the convolutional layers. This change can be seen in this [part of the code](https://gist.github.com/sahiliitm/bed9511d15ba0c45adf3c33210d59232#file-cifar10-py-L91).

For simplicity, i have removed all parameter training operations and even loss computations. The current model only computes logits (forward pass) again and again.
The unmodified code (can be executed by setting the `use_outerp` flag to `False`) uses approximately .4 GB RAM
whereas the modified code (with outer product of vectors used as the convolutional weight tensor) uses a disproportionately high 5.6 GB RAM.

Any idea why this is the case?
My intuition as to why this might happen is that maybe the outer product operations are being executed every single time that the conv filter is needed instead of being executed exactly once in every forward pass. Is this really the case? Is there a way to fix this?

Steps to reproduce:

To run the default version of the code (low memory footprint):

`python train.py --use_outerp='False'`

To run the modified version of the code (high memory footprint):

`python train.py --use_outerp='True'`

Operating System:

Ubuntu 14.04

Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN:

None, I'm using the CPU version of TF.

The output from `python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)"`:

0.10.0rc0

Using tcmalloc as suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6688) didn't help.

Comment: How do you check your memory usage btw?

Comment: I'm only seeing 4.4GB RSS usage in top in tensorflow 0.12

Comment: Sorry. You are (almost) correct. I was reporting the total system memory utilization. Indeed, the memory used by TF alone is lower but still disproportionately higher. The unedited code takes ~ 440 MB RAM whereas the memory usage of modified code grows to 5.6 GB over time (I think after 10 minutes of usage)

Comment: RSS Memory usage shouldn't grow over time. If it does, that it's a problem in OS or a bug in TensorFlow itself (ie, using default system allocator can cause unbounded memory allocation). Virtual Memory usage can grow, but that's not a problem. You can see detailed breakdown of memory usage in a single TensorFlow step using timeline, or by parsing vlog messages as done [here](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/notebooks/blob/master/mnist-memory.ipynb)

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean, it gets stuck and keeps growing memory before even getting to the first run call

Comment: I think the 'getting stuck' behavior is to be expected. I am allocating lots of 1-D tensors and creating thousands of outer product operations. The strange part for me is that it consumes so much RAM.Of course, this is only a toy example. I was trying an idea with a 19-Layer network and it just consumes all of 128 GB ram and still doesn't work.

Comment: Btw, the memory usage does not grow unboundedly with time. I haven't used the timeline tool yet. A close monitoring of memory usage using top reveals that memory usage oscillates between ~2.6 GB and ~5.7 GB but never exceeds 6 GB. I'll definitely checkout timeline based profiling. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, I tried a bit but it's hard to reproduce, my timeline tools need latest version of tensorflow, and it wasn't trivial to modify your code to work with version 0.12 (cifar was looking for "cifar10.loss". The best way to start is to make smaller example, and check that memory allocations match your expectations using stat summarizer -- https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/08afccbe087171881ceafc0c98abca05